# Shifting html table right while retaining width

Tags: html, html-table

I want to shift a couple of HTML tables on my page to the right. So I have added `style=margin-left:30px` to the table definition. The problem is that I want the width to remain at 100% but a horizontal scrollbar appears. So I added this CSS:

```
html,body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This removes the scrollbar fine but it just truncates the righthand 30px of the table which includes some right-justified buttons that I need.

How do I shift the table right and keep the entire table within the smaller width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect. No shift at all. Code: '<table id="tblLI" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" style="padding-left:30px">'

Comment: I spoke too soon. I added a `<div style="padding-left:30px">' around the table and it worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE < 9, you can use `calc` for the table's width and still offset it with `margin-left`:

```css
width: calc(100% - 30px);
margin-left: 30px;
```